# ag-grid cellEditor select with object values

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

I want to select from a list of users:

**user.ts**

```
export class User
{
    constructor (public id: number, public userName : string){}
}
```

the column definition look like this:

```
this.columns = [
                {headerName: "Assigned", field:"user.userName", 
                 editable: true ,cellEditor: "select", 
                 cellEditorParams: {values : this.users.map(u=> u.userName)},
]
```

I want to be able to select a user from the list and get in cellValueChanged the object.

Is there an option that the `user` will be the field and not a string value and still the `user.username` will be shown in the cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found an workaround to get `'select'` working with `key` and `value`.

```
var colorsNames = [];
colors.forEach(color=> {
  colorsNames.push(color.name);
})
...

{
  headerName: "Color",
  field: "colorId",
  width: 150,
  editable: true,
  cellEditor: 'select',
  cellRenderer: function (data: any) {
    var color = colors.find(color => color.id == data.value || color.name == data.value);
    // here I've added the check for 'color.id' and 'color.name' because initailly from DB will com the id and afterwards form selectparams will come the name
    return color.name;
  },
  onCellValueChanged: function (data: any) {
    /**
     * because 'select' does not offer us the possibility to use 'key-value' as traditional,
     * we will use only values in 'select' and changed to 'id' when will be saved.
     */
    var serviceTypeName = data.data.serviceTypeId;
    data.data.serviceTypeId = serviceTypes.find(serviceType => serviceType.name == serviceTypeName).id;
  },
  cellEditorParams: {
    values: colorsNames
  }
},
```

The idea is that inside `select params` we will give only strings and we will try to find the `id` of object based on the `name`. Important is that we agreed that `name` is unique field.

After managing to get it working, I realized that indeed the `select` is a very poor solution. Is not working properly and I would not advice to use it.

@Yonatan Lilling For any question, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for javascript in https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-reference-data/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0

i create my array:

```
var Etat_acces = {"1": "Annulée", "2": "Validée", "3": "A valider CEX", "4": "Demandée", "5":"Initialisée"};
```

and in my columnDefs:

```
{
headerName: "Etat Ni", field: "etat_acces", editable: true, cellEditor:'select',

            cellEditorParams: {
                values: extractValues(Etat_acces)
            },
            valueFormatter: function (params) {
                return lookupValue(Etat_acces, params.value);
            },
            valueParser: function (params) {
                return lookupKey(Etat_acces, params.newValue);
            }

}
```

and for the three function :

```
function extractValues(mappings) {
return Object.keys(mappings);
}

function lookupValue(mappings, key) {
    return mappings[key];
}

function lookupKey(mappings, name) {
    for (var key in mappings) {
        if (mappings.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (name === mappings[key]) {
                return key;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can be useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

pass the array with stringified objects, and in value formatter parse back the stringified object to get the json object back. This can be used for simple objects.

make an array with stringified objects

```
someObject.forEach(element => {
  someArray.push(JSON.stringify(element))       
});
```

in value formatter call the function which parse back the stringified object in json object

```
valueformatter : jsonValueFormatter
```

function for reproducing the object

```
function jsonValueFormatter(params){
  obj = JSON.parse(params.value)
  return obj.someProperty;
}
```